# SSIS - 2nd Script Task not being executed in Foreach Loop Container

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, script-task, foreach-loop-container

I have 2 script tasks in my foreach loop container in an SSIS package. See picture. The first script task *Determine which file is presented* gets executed just fine. However, the second one *Archive Broker File* does not get executed at all.

I can see in the progress that the script tasks gets validated but no execution at all. The only thing it needs to do is to rename a file and move it to a different location.

Any idea what's going on especially since the first script task gets executed without any issues.

Thanks,
Daniel

[image: Archive Broker File not being executed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

It will not be executed if the three data flow tasks are not executed since you are using precedence constraints *(link between tasks)* with **Logical AND** condition

### Solution

Double click on any precedence constraint going from any Data Flow Task to the script Task and change the condition to **Logical OR**

**Info from official documentation**

Based on [Precedence Constraints official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/precedence-constraints?view=sql-server-2017):

> **Logical AND**
>  Select to specify that multiple precedence constraints on the same executable must be evaluated together. All
>   constraints must evaluate to True.
>
> `This type of precedence constraint appears as a solid green,
>   highlighted or blue line.`
>
> **Logical OR**
>  Select to specify that multiple precedence constraints on the same executable must be evaluated together. At
>   least one constraint must evaluate to True.
>
> `This type of precedence constraint appears as a dotted green,
>   highlighted, or blue line.`

---

**Other helpful articles**

You can read more about precedence constraints in the following article:

- [Working with Precedence Constraints in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssis+precedence+constraint+logical+or&oq=ssis+precedence+constraint+or&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l4.7286j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- [Using Expressions On Precedence Constraints in Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5023/using-expressions-on-precedence-constraints-in-integration-services/)
- [Using Precedence Constraints In SSIS](https://mindmajix.com/ssis/using-precedence-constraints)